# SVG Filter using feImage as input to feDisplacementMap

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I am trying to use svg filters to add a displacement map to an image. This is my code:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <filter id="a" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300">
      <feImage xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/TKNyL9Q.jpg" result="heatmap"/>
      <feDisplacementMap scale="15" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in2="heatmap" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" height="300" width="300" filter="url(#a)" />
  </svg>
```

This is supposed to take the beagle image and apply a grid displacement map to it but it has no effect.

Oddly, switching `in` with `in2` in the `<feDisplacementMap>` tag does work but in reverse showing a grid image with a beagle map fine.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Alibasher/pen/dyRNmzg) example.

Why does it only work one way?

Comment: The code is fine I think. You can see something similar on [xChannelSelector | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xChannelSelector). The only way that I can make this filter work is by running **all** files from the same domain. I'm running Firefox 91.

Comment: @chrwahl Thanks. I've tested this on Chrome 93.0.4577.63, and there is no difference when ran with local files.

Comment: Sound like you tested the files directly from the filesystem. If you have the files on your computer, you need to run a web server with the SVG/HTML file, the feImage and the beagle image.

Comment: @chrwahl Oh interesting, hosting it does indeed fix it. Thanks

Comment: I think that knowing the files have to be on the same domain and that you have to run a web server when testing locally is useful enough information to be a full answer. @chrwahl

Answer (score 0):

it seems the in & in2 parameters need to match up with the source graphic itself not the .heatmap.

I amended the  on the first: 'Beagle with heatmap filter' to this:

```
<feDisplacementMap scale="15" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in2="SourceGraphic" in="SourceGraphic"/><!-- -->
    </filter>
```

Let me know if this is the result you was looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not quite what I'm after.
Your code uses the beagle image as both the image and the displacement map, but I want to use the heatmap/grid image as the displacement map instead.